# What is the % doing while handling strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string-interpolation

I was going through some piece of code when I found this line

```
if ('%{test}' % {:test => 'replaced'} == 'replaced')
  # If this works, we are all good to go.
```

Why is `'%{test}' % {:test => 'replaced'}` returning value `"replaced"`? What exactly is `%` doing over here?

Comment: PS: Please edit the post if you come up with a better title.

Comment: Nice warning :-) I was reading it also.. Seems to me perfect title.. +1 for good title.

Comment: In case you are new to Ruby, the receiver of the method `℅` is an instance of the class `String`, so you will find documentation for `%` under [String#%](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/String.html#method-i-25).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is doing "interpolation". The value `"replaced"` of the key `:test` of the hash is inserted to the `%{test}` position in the original string `'%{test}'`.

The `%` can take a string, array, or hash depending on the need. When you only have a single slot in the template as in this case, it is better to use `%s` and pass a string like

```
"%s" % "replaced"
```

With the particular example, it is not useful.

It becomes useful when you want to replace a part of a string. 
For example, if you want to generate a series of strings:

```
"Hello World", "Hey World", "Bye World"
```

you can have a template string `s = "%s World"` and interpolate things into it like

```
s % "Hello"
s % "Hey" 
s % "Bye"
```